The definition and properties of the restriction of integral （rational） cohomology to a subspace within the ambient space.
This seems to be a fairly standard question, but I am somewhat confused when considering it using Čech cohomology theory.
Let $X$ be a paracompact topological space admitting good cover and $Y$ a subspace of $X$. Assume $\alpha\in H^p(X, \mathbb{Z})$ (or $\alpha\in H^p(X, \mathbb{Q})$ or or $\alpha\in H^p(X, \mathbb{R})$) be a cohomology class. ($H^p(X, \mathbb{Z})$ denotes the sheaf cohomology of the locally constant sheaf $\mathbb{Z}$, a priori.)

Question: What is the definition of the restriction $\alpha|_Y$ to
$Y$, and is $\alpha|_Y\in H^p(Y, \mathbb{Z})$?

I have seen from many references that $\alpha|_Y$ is well-defined and $\alpha|_Y\in H^p(Y, \mathbb{Z})$.
Now I will try to use Čech cohomology theory to define $\left.\alpha\right|_Y$ as follows. Since $X$ admits a good cover, we can choose a good cover $\left\{U_i\right\}_i$ (which is clearly an acyclic cover of $\mathbb{Z}$ ) and use the Leray isomorphism theorem. Then $\alpha$ can be represented by a p-cocycle $\left\{\alpha_{i_0\cdots i_p}\right\}$ with respect to $\left\{U_i\right\}_i$. However, it may happen that $\left\{U_i \cap Y\right\}_i$ is not a good cover of $Y$. Therefore, $\left\{\left.\alpha_{i_0\cdots i_p}\right|_Y\right\}$ may not represent an element of $H^p(Y, \mathbb{Z})$.

This seems like a good advertisement for using singular cohomology instead, which is among other things designed to make functoriality as transparent as possible.

Just don't use good covers for the definition of the sheaf cohomology, use limits instead. It all should be in Eilenberg and Steenrod.
